# Pandas if column contains string then write to second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I want to be able to search column(snippet_matched) from DF2 for see if it has a partial match with anything from column(Search) in DF1. if it does contain it I then want to write "Yes" to DF1 column(HR). Is something like this possible?

df1

```
Number    Search     HRC
 1       1 test game 
 2       2 test game
 3       3 test game
```

df2

```
Title  Snipped_Match
 User     Win  
 Sony     1 game
```

Expected

```
Number    Search       HRC
 1       1 test game   Yes
 2       2 test game   Yes
 3       3 test game   Yes
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by 'contains' Do you mean exact match or partial match? Please define it more strictly.

Comment: Partial Match sorry

Comment: Updated. missed that bit sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function for the partial matching and apply it on the df1['Search'] column. See below:

```
def match(cell, column):
    column=[set(i.split()) for i in column]
    cell=set(cell.split())
    return 'Yes' if any(k-cell==set() for k in column) else 'No'

df1['HR']=df1['Search'].apply(lambda x: match(x, df2['Snipped_Match']))
```

Result:

```
>>> print(df1)

   Number       Search   HR
0       1  1 test game  Yes
1       2  2 test game   No
2       3  3 test game   No
```

Comment: just populated the HRC column with False?

Comment: Code updated, please try again. Can you confirm that you want items of df1['Search'] to be included in df2['snippet_matched'] and in that case the df1['HR'] respective row will be filled with ''Yes' otherwise 'No'?

Comment: Just updated. I need some sort of contains. So if df2['Snippet_matched'] CONTAINS something in df1['Search'] then YES

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please check my comment under your question

Comment: Updated. it was a partial match

Comment: Updated, please check and let me know if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226055/discussion-between-will-and-ioatzimas).